# call of IBM 'CSNBOWH' checksum function

Tags: cobol

Can some one please help me to call this ibm  function 'CSNBOWH' in my cobol program
Is this declaration of parameters good?
[my declaration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LI0pr.png)

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According to the knowledgecenter page, the chaining_vector_length for CSNBOWH must be set to 128, and the chaining_vector be a 128 byte buffer.

Make sure the text_length matches the size of the text, along with all the other lengths for data items.  Seems hash_length is either 32 or 64 (and similar sized hash buffer).

Other than that, it just seems to be a CALL with all the fields listed in the proper order.

Instead of a leaving a link, just use the search engine you mistrust the least with "CSNBOWH ibm" to find the Knowledge Center page.

I can't speak to the down votes, DRY, but you'll find StackOverflow is more friendly when you state things you've tried, errors experienced, with actual messages and such.

Best is when there is a short listing that people can try quickly when helping a stranger.  When you make others think or work too much, answers will be less forthcoming. Volunteers here may not bother if they seem to be putting in more effort than the person asking the question, *for non theory related problems*.  *Pictures of code is not a listing, paste code in code blocks or backticks*, which is far more help provider friendly.

Answer (score 1):

My declaration

```
*   VARIABLES
       02 RETURN_CODE           PIC 9(8) COMP-5.
       02 REASON_CODE           PIC 9(8) COMP-5.
       02 EXIT_DATA_LENGTH      PIC 9(8) COMP-5.
       02 EXIT_DATA             PIC X(04).
       02 RULE_ARRAY_COUNT      PIC 9(8) COMP-5 VALUE 1.
       02 RULE_ARRAY            PIC X(8) VALUE 'MD5'.
       02 TEXT_LENGTH           PIC 9(8) COMP-5 VALUE 128.
       02 TEXT_MESSAGE     PIC X(20) VALUE 'xxxxxxx'.
       02 CHAINING_VECTOR_LENGTH  PIC 9(8) COMP-5 VALUE 128.
       02 CHAINING_VECTOR       PIC X(128).
       02 HASH_LENGTH           PIC 9(8) COMP-5 VALUE 16.
       02 HASH                  PIC X(16).
       02 MYAPI                 PIC X(08) VALUE 'CSNBOWH'.
```

in working call like this an display after

```
CALL    'CSNBOWH'    USING  RETURN_CODE
                      REASON_CODE
                      EXIT_DATA_LENGTH
                      EXIT_DATA
                      RULE_ARRAY_COUNT
                      RULE_ARRAY
                      TEXT_LENGTH
                      TEXT_MESSAGE
                      CHAINING_VECTOR_LENGTH
                      CHAINING_VECTOR
                      HASH_LENGTH
                      HASH.

DISPLAY 'RETURN_CODE : ' RETURN_CODE
DISPLAY 'REASON_CODE : ' REASON_CODE
DISPLAY 'EXIT_DATA_LENGTH : ' EXIT_DATA_LENGTH
DISPLAY 'EXIT_DATA : ' EXIT_DATA
DISPLAY 'RULE_ARRAY_COUNT : ' RULE_ARRAY_COUNT
DISPLAY 'RULE_ARRAY : ' RULE_ARRAY
DISPLAY 'TEXT_LENGTH : ' TEXT_LENGTH
DISPLAY 'TEXT_MESSAGE : ' TEXT_MESSAGE
DISPLAY 'CHAINING_VECTOR_LENGTH : 'CHAINING_VECTOR_LENGTH
DISPLAY 'CHAINING_VECTOR : ' CHAINING_VECTOR
DISPLAY 'HASH_LENGTH : ' HASH_LENGTH
DISPLAY 'HASH1: ' HASH
```

enjoy!